# Is there a published schedule for Disney World's extended opening hours?

Tags: disney, orlando, opening-hours

At http://disneyworld.disney.go.com/planning-guides/in-depth-advice/extended-theme-park-hours/ it says

> Each day, one of the 4 Walt Disney World theme parks opens one hour early or remains open up to 3 hours after regular closing time.

Is the days for each park published anywhere?  I had no luck searching myself but I'm not sure where to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the schedule for the rest of 2012, which I got from [here](http://www.themouseforless.com/tripplanning/wdwparks/emh.shtml).  It was apparently compiled from [Disney's calendar pages](http://disneyworld.disney.go.com/calendars/).  According to the page you linked to, "Upon check-in at a Walt Disney World Resort hotel, Guests will receive a schedule detailing when each park offers Extra Magic Hours" so if any last minute changes have occurred, that will be the most accurate.  But the information below should allow you to start planning.

```
July 2012
Morning Extra Magic Hours
Magic Kingdom - July 5, 12, 19, 26
Epcot - July 6, 13, 20, 27
Disney's Hollywood Studios - July 7, 14, 21, 28
Animal Kingdom - July 2, 4, 9, 11, 16, 18, 23, 25, 30
Blizzard Beach - July 5, 12, 19, 26
Typhoon Lagoon - July 4, 11, 18, 25

Evening Extra Magic Hours
Magic Kingdom - July 3, 6, 8, 13, 15, 20, 27, 29
Epcot - July 1, 10, 17, 24
Disney's Hollywood Studios - July 2, 9, 16, 23, 30
Animal Kingdom - No Evening Extra Magic Hours
Blizzard Beach - No Evening Extra Magic Hours
Typhoon Lagoon - No Evening Extra Magic Hours

August 2012
Morning Extra Magic Hours
Magic Kingdom - August 2, 9, 16, 23, 30
Epcot - August 3, 10, 17, 24, 31
Disney's Hollywood Studios - August 4, 11, 18, 25
Animal Kingdom - August 1, 6, 8, 13, 15, 20, 22, 27, 29
Blizzard Beach - August 2, 9, 16, 23
Typhoon Lagoon - August 1, 8, 15, 22

Evening Extra Magic Hours
Magic Kingdom - August 3, 5, 10, 12, 17, 19, 24, 26
Epcot - August 7, 14, 21, 28
Disney's Hollywood Studios - August 6, 13, 20, 27
Animal Kingdom - No Evening Extra Magic Hours
Blizzard Beach - No Evening Extra Magic Hours
Typhoon Lagoon - No Evening Extra Magic Hours

September 2012
Morning Extra Magic Hours
Magic Kingdom - September 6, 13, 20, 27
Epcot - September 4, 11, 18, 25
Disney's Hollywood Studios - September 1, 8, 15, 22, 28
Animal Kingdom - September 3, 5, 10, 14, 17, 21, 24, 29

Evening Extra Magic Hours
Magic Kingdom - September 2, 9, 16, 23
Epcot - September 7, 12, 19, 26
Disney's Hollywood Studios - September 3, 10, 17, 24
Animal Kingdom - No Evening Extra Magic Hours

October 2012
Morning Extra Magic Hours
Magic Kingdom - October 4, 11, 18, 25
Epcot - October 2, 9, 16, 23, 30
Disney's Hollywood Studios - October 6, 13, 20, 27
Animal Kingdom - October 1, 5, 8, 12, 15, 19, 22, 26, 28

Evening Extra Magic Hours
Magic Kingdom - October 1, 7, 15, 22
Epcot - October 3, 10, 17, 24, 31
Disney's Hollywood Studios - October 8, 14, 21, 29
Animal Kingdom - No Evening Extra Magic Hours

November 2012
Morning Extra Magic Hours
Magic Kingdom - November 1, 8, 15, 22, 29
Epcot - November 6, 13, 20, 27
Disney's Hollywood Studios - November 3, 10, 17, 24
Animal Kingdom - November 2, 4, 9, 12, 14, 19, 21, 26, 28

Evening Extra Magic Hours
Magic Kingdom - November 10, 11, 18, 26
Epcot - November 7, 16, 23, 30
Disney's Hollywood Studios - November 5, 12, 19, 25
Animal Kingdom - No Evening Extra Magic Hours

December 2012
Morning Extra Magic Hours
Magic Kingdom - December 6, 13, 20, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31
Epcot - December 4, 11, 18, 23
Disney's Hollywood Studios - December 1, 8, 15, 22, 24
Animal Kingdom - December 3, 5, 10, 12, 17, 19, 25, 28, 29, 30, 31

Evening Extra Magic Hours
Magic Kingdom - December 3, 10, 17, 23, 28, 30
Epcot - December 7, 14, 21, 25, 27
Disney's Hollywood Studios - December 2, 9, 16, 26, 29, 31
Animal Kingdom - No Evening Extra Magic Hours
```

Comment: Cheers, I'd read the site as meaning that it would be a single park open for extended hours each days but those appear all over the place!

Comment: I believe on any given day, only one of the four parks will have morning extra magic hours, and one of the others (but never the same one) may have extra evening magic hours.  In addition, one of the two water parks may have morning extra magic hours.  The water parks and the animal kingdom never have extra evening magic hours.